# Change/Replace Fragments according to Radio button selection

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

i have Activity which as two radio buttons 
i want to change/replace fragments according to radio button selection

```
public class SignUp extends FragmentActivity implements OnCheckedChangeListener {

RadioGroup rg;
Signup_BloodBank sb;  //fragment 1
Signup_User su;   //fragment 2
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

    rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg1);
    rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

    sb = new Signup_BloodBank();
    su = new Signup_User();

    RadioButton btn1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rbBloodBank);
    btn1.setChecked(true);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.linear2, sb).commit();


}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

    ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    switch (checkedId) {
    case R.id.rbBloodBank:
            ft.replace(R.id.linear2,sb);
    case R.id.rbUser:
        ft.replace(R.id.linear2,su);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    ft.commit();
}
```

}

### Fragment1

```
public class Signup_BloodBank extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        container.removeAllViews();
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sing_up__bb, null);
    }

}
```

### Fragment2

`public class Signup_User extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    container.removeAllViews();
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sign_up__user, null);
}
}`

Comment: explain your issue ?

Comment: getting error msg.. unfortunately your app has stopped.. radio1 is checked by default and Fragment1 is added and displayed.. but when i click another radion button i need to replace the first one. and again if i click on any radio i want to see appropriate fragment.. Please Help

Answer (score 0):

try the following code..............

1.first give the name to radio button like this

In xml file

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

         <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rd1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="fragment_one" />


        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rd2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="fragment_two" />        

        </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

then in your java file....................

RadioButton rd1,rd2,rd_choose;
RadioGroup rGroup;

```
    rd1=(RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rd1);
    rd2=(RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rd2);   


    rGroup=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    rGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

              int id=group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
              rd_choose=(RadioButton) findViewById(id);
              String rd_text=rbtanswer.getText().toString();

               if(rd_text.equals(fragment_one))
               {
                  //  replace fragment here
               }

               else{
                  //  replace fragment here
                }


        }
    });
```

Hope it will helpfull for u

Comment: hi.. there is no issue with radio button selection.. issue with fragment replacement.. getting error unfortunately your app stopped

Answer (score 0):

Without a more detailed explanation of the issue you're facing, I'm going to assume it's not working for you.

On cursory look through, the following code you are missing the .commit() after .replace.

```
case R.id.rbBloodBank:
    ft.replace(R.id.linear2,sb);
case R.id.rbUser:
    ft.replace(R.id.linear2,su);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should define both radio button after defining radio group .
Try this following code:

```
 RadioButton rd1,rd2,rd_choose;
RadioGroup rGroup;


        rGroup=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        rd1=(RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rd1);
        rd2=(RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rd2);  

        rGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
android.support.v4.app.Fragment f = null;
 switch (group.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {

            case "R.id.rbBloodBank":
                f = new Signup_BloodBank();

                break;

            case " R.id.rbUser":
                f =new Signup_User();

                break;





            }
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.linear2, f).addToBackStack(null).commit();

        });
```